# Laravel try / catch on not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, error-handling, try-catch

I've searched a few questions for a reason my code is *not* throwing an error correctly, but I can't figure it out.

I have the following function in my controller

```
<?php
public function suspend($id)
{
    try {
        $this->collection = $this->class::find($id);

        $this->collection->delete();

        return $this->respond_with_success();

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        return $this->respond_with_error('Failed to suspend resource with id: ' . $id);
    }
}
```

For reference, I'm using soft deletes. I can suspend a resource once no problem. If I try to suspend one that's already suspended, Laravel correctly throws a 500 as I can see in the log file `/storage/logs/laravel.log`

This is part of the error I see;

`local.ERROR: Call to a member function delete() on null....`

Without using
`withTrashed()` in the query, a row quite obviously cannot be found. So this makes sense.

Great...so why does my `catch` not actually catch anything? I see a 500 error in the browser, but my application *should* allow me to continue and handle that error correctly. But it just falls over completely...

The `respond_with_error` function is below. I've tried changing the `$code` to 200 in testing, but this doesn't change anything. I've tested returning a simple string rather than with this function to no avail, so I don't think there's anything wrong with this part.

```
<?php
protected function respond_with_error($message = 'error', $code = 500)
{
    return Response::json([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => $message,
    ], $code);
}
```

I'm running Laravel 5.6.29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to address this.  The first thing to note is `ERROR: Call to a member function delete() on null` is not an exception, it is a fatal error.

1. You can use `findOrFail` instead of `find` to throw an Exception when the model is not found and that will work.
2. You could also catch `Throwable` instead of `Exception` to catch errors and exceptions (as of PHP7) or just `Error` to catch errors.

> As the Error hierarchy does not inherit from Exception, code that uses catch (Exception $e) { ... } blocks to handle uncaught exceptions in PHP 5 will find that these Errors are not caught by these blocks. Either a catch (Error $e) { ... } block or a set_exception_handler() handler is required.

Read more on PHP7 Error Handling here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense, thank you. In this instance I've tested with `Throwable` which works, though I can see how `findOrFail` would also be of use.